# Statistics Question? Monte Carlo Simulation? Combinatorics?

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, computer-science

- A term in an NBA team's lease agreement states that it must pay a penalty fee every time it fails to reach $17,000$ attendees in three consecutive home games.
- The onerous fee has caused the team to request assistance in assessing its risk. The team estimates the probability it will reach $17,000$ attendees in a home game is $75$%, and each game has an equal likelihood of eclipsing the $17,000$ threshold.
- Given the $75\ \%$ likelihood of hitting that number each game, what are the odds that the team will avoid a three-game streak with attendance under $17,000$ for the entire season ?.
- Please build a simple simulator to determine your answer ( note that there are $41$ regular season home games; assume each game is independent ).

How do I approach this problem and simulate, perhaps with python script ?.

Comment: The bigger question is how would one roll for attendance? Is attendance normally distributed? Exponential? Uniform? Surely the arena in which the team plays has a maximum capacity. I think this question can't really be answered well without that information.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Isn't that answered by "each game has equal likelihood..." ( although I think this should be probability).

Comment: @gary: No, "equal likelihood" is not the same as "independent". (But I did overlook the parenthesis at the end specifying an assumption of independence).

Comment: @HenningMakholm: For the effects of this question, if they are independent, then the probability is the same. Since it is the same, isn't that enough?

Comment: @gary: No, that is confused and invalid logic. Even if it were true that independent events have the same probability (they don't necessarily -- consider drawing one card from a shuffled standard deck of cards; the events "it's diamonds" and "it's an ace" are independent but have different probabilities"), you're trying to reason "P implies Q, but Q, therefore P", which is not valid.

Comment: @Sharath: Are you asking how to _code_ a simulation in Python? That sounds more like a question for Stack Overflow than a good question for here. But even so, I think the people at SO would like to see a more focused question than this, with some effort to at least plan it out for yourself and some indication of _which facet of the task_ you're facing difficulty with.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: No, I am saying that it is stated that each game has the same probability of hitting the target, and assume independence.I am saying this is enough for an unambiguous answer.

Comment: If you ask the question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), I will remove my answer and post it more appropriately there.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly,assuming independence, you can find $1-P$(1 or 2 games only will fall below $75 \%$). The probability that exactly one game will miss out is $41C1(.25)(.75)^{40}$ ( $41C1$ ways of choosing that one game, with probability $.25\%$ and for $2$ games, it is $41C2 (.25)^2(.75)^{39}$ ; choose the 2 games that will not hit the target in $41C2$ ways , each combination having probability  $(0.25)^2 (.75)^{39}$ , where $nCm$ stands for "$n$ Choose $m$".
EDIT: As pointed out, I missed the part on *consecutive* games. Will be back to reqrite ASAP.

Comment: The task the OP has to solve is not merely to _find the probability_, but to "build a simple simulator to determine your answer".

Comment: Yes, but as you stated, this is not the type of task done in MSE, that is a task for a programming site, which MSE is not. I am doing the Math part.

Comment: The question states 3 consecutive home games. Not just 3 games total.

Comment: @PJF49: Ah, sorry, I am kind of gone, but will change later. Will write an edit in the post to this effect.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: I checked StackOverflow for this question but could not find it, which is why I am posting code in a mathematics stack exchange*

The following python program should accurately simulate the scenario you've explained over a user inputted number of seasons. I don't program in python often so I apologize if this is not conventional or neat. Because I quickly wrote this, I did not add documentation to the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""simulaiton.py, by B. Standage. 2017-07-26"""

from random import randint

def main():

    lossStreak = 0
    loosingStreaks = 0
    seasonsAvoided = 0
    seasons = input("Number of seasons you wish the simulation to run for: ")

    while (seasons > 0):
        avoidedLoosingStreak = "Yes"
        count = 0

        for x in range (0, 40):
            if(randint(0,100) <= 75):
                lossStreak = 0
            else:
                lossStreak += 1
                if(lossStreak == 3):
                    avoidedLoosingStreak = "No"
                    count += 1


        if(avoidedLoosingStreak == "Yes"):
            seasonsAvoided += 1
        else:
            loosingStreaks += count
        seasons -= 1

    print("Total seasons avoiding a three game loosings treak: " + str(seasonsAvoided))
    print("Total seasons facing a three game loosings treak: " + str(loosingStreaks))
    print("In a total of " + str(seasons) + " the experimental odds of having less than 17,000 fans in attendance for at leas$

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Let an attendance over (or equal to) 17000 be a success and anything fewer a failure.

Let $a_n$ be the probability that after n games so far there hasn't been a run of 3 consecutive failures and that the nth game was a success. Similarly let $b_n$ be the probability that after n games so far there hasn't been a run of 3 consecutive failures, the nth game was a failure but the (n-1)th was a success and let $c_n$ be the probability that after n games so far there hasn't been a run of 3 consecutive failures, the nth game was a failure and the (n-1)th was also a failure.

This gives us the recurrance relationship:

$$a_n = \frac{3}{4}(a_{n-1} + b_{n-1} + c_{n-1})\\b_n = \frac{1}{4}a_{n-1}\\c_n = \frac{1}{4}b_{n-1}\\(a_2=\frac{3}{4}, b_2=\frac{3}{16}, c_2=\frac{1}{16})$$

Then the probability of going the entire season (41 games) without three consecutive failures is $a_{41} + b_{41} + c_{41}$

Then using the following python code I got the probability to be approximately 0.61866:

```
a = 3/4
b = 3/16
c = 1/16
for x in range(39):
    a, b, c = 3/4*(a+b+c), 1/4*(a), 1/4*(b)
print(a+b+c)
```